# How to get Tflite model output in c++?

Tags: python, c++, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I have a tflite model for mask detection with a sigmoid layer that outputs values between 0[mask] and 1[no_mask]

I examined the input and output node using netron and here's what I got:

[image: Netron showing model input and output]

I tested the model for inference in python and it works great.

```
# A simple inference pipline 

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2


# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="efficient_net.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Rescale to [1,32,32,1].
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
img = cv2.imread("nomask.jpg")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
input_data = img_gray[ ..., tf.newaxis]
input_data  =tf.image.resize(input_data, [32,32])
input_data = input_data[ tf.newaxis,...]
input_data = np.array(input_data, dtype=np.float32)


# setting input 
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)


interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data[0][0])
```

I tried doing the same using c++ but I get either 0 or no output at all

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;


#define TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(x)                                  \
    if (!(x))                                                    \
    {                                                            \
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        exit(1);                                                 \
    }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "minimal <tflite model>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    const char* filename = argv[1];



    // read image file
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("D:\\nomask.png");

    // convert to float; BGR -> Grayscale
    cv::Mat inputImg;
    img.convertTo(inputImg, CV_32FC1);
    cv::cvtColor(inputImg, inputImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // resize image as model input
    cv::resize(inputImg, inputImg, cv::Size(32, 32));
    
    
    // Load model
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model =
        tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(filename);
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(model != nullptr);

    // Build the interpreter with the InterpreterBuilder.
    // Note: all Interpreters should be built with the InterpreterBuilder,
    // which allocates memory for the Intrepter and does various set up
    // tasks so that the Interpreter can read the provided model.
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    builder(&interpreter);
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter != nullptr);

    // Allocate tensor buffers.
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->AllocateTensors() == kTfLiteOk);
    

    // Fill input buffers
    // TODO(user): Insert code to fill input tensors.
    // Note: The buffer of the input tensor with index `i` of type T can
    float* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0);
    input = inputImg.ptr<float>(0);
    
    // Run inference
    TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->Invoke() == kTfLiteOk);
    printf("\n\n=== Post-invoke Interpreter State ===\n");
    

     
     
    
    float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(149);
    std::cout << output[0];
  

    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the output index to 0 instead of 149 but I always get a small output value indicating that there's a mask whatever the input is (This does not happen in python inference)
what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: I have minimal knowledge of C++. Have you checked the important notices at documentation for resizing and allocating tensors? https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_c

Comment: Tensors are represented by integers, in order to avoid string comparisons (and any fixed dependency on string libraries).
An interpreter must not be accessed from concurrent threads.
Memory allocation for input and output tensors must be triggered by calling AllocateTensors() right after resizing tensors.

Comment: Thanks @Farmaker for your comment I managed to get the code working :)

Comment: Nice! Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code now works fine with these changes :

```
memcpy(input,img.data,32*32*sizeof(float));
```

instead of

```
 input = inputImg.ptr<float>(0);
```

and using index 0 for output

```
float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);
```

The index here indicates the order of the output tensor not it's location

Comment: this worked for me. I guess it points to the starting of the output, if I have set input an image with dimensions [1, 160, 160, 3] using memcpy command, how can I extract the complete image from the output? Please guide me.